# getJuiceDescription method always returns same result

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to set custom Strings for each specific click in the alert dialog. It works perfectly for the title but when using the same code to try and put a custom message in the Alert Dialog it is not working, it always returns "Iono". My code is below along with a picture of what I am talking about.

**ViewController**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var galleryItems: [GalleryItem] = []
var listOfDescriptions: [String] = []
var listOfJuiceDescriptions: [String] = []

// MARK: -
// MARK: - View Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initGalleryItems()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    populateList()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}

private func initGalleryItems() {

    var items = [GalleryItem]()
    let inputFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("items", ofType: "plist")

    let inputDataArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: inputFile!)

    for inputItem in inputDataArray as! [Dictionary<String, String>] {
        let galleryItem = GalleryItem(dataDictionary: inputItem)
        items.append(galleryItem)
    }

    galleryItems = items
}
private func populateList() {
    listOfDescriptions.append("Valhaha");
    listOfDescriptions.append("Unicorns blood");
    listOfDescriptions.append("Rasberry");
        listOfDescriptions.append("Orange");
}
private func getDescription(position: Int) -> String {
    if (position<listOfDescriptions.count) {
    return listOfDescriptions[position]
    } else {
        return "Custom Label"
    }
}

private func populateJuices() {
    listOfJuiceDescriptions.append("warm vanilla")
    listOfJuiceDescriptions.append("Fruit Punch")
    listOfJuiceDescriptions.append("uhh rasberry nigga")
    listOfJuiceDescriptions.append("so you never tasted an orange before?")
}

private func getJuiceDescription(position: Int) -> String {
    if (position<listOfJuiceDescriptions.count) {
        return listOfJuiceDescriptions[position]
    }
    else {
        return "Iono"
    }
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return galleryItems.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("GalleryItemCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GalleryItemCollectionViewCell

    cell.setGalleryItem(galleryItems[indexPath.row])
    cell.itemNameLabel.text=getDescription(indexPath.row)
    return cell

}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let commentView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryItemCommentView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GalleryItemCommentView

    commentView.commentLabel.text = "Supplementary view of kind \(kind)"

    return commentView
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: getDescription(indexPath.row), message: getJuiceDescription(indexPath.row), preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Destructive, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(alertAction)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: - UICollectionViewFlowLayout

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let picDimension = self.view.frame.size.width / 4.0
    return CGSizeMake(picDimension, picDimension + 31)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let leftRightInset = self.view.frame.size.width / 14.0
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftRightInset, 0, leftRightInset)
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `getJuicesDescription` function to get the description.  This function gets the description from the `listOfJuiceDescriptions` array. The `listOfJuiceDescriptions` array is created in the `populateJuices` function.

However, I don't see anywhere in your code that calls `populateJuices`.  I see a call to `populateList` in `viewDidLoad` but no call to `populateJuices`.

This means when `getJuicesDescription` is called the array is empty and your `if` statement returns `Iono`.